# Invariance of the Rindler metric under coordinate transformation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

The Rindler geometry is described by the following line element
$$
\mathrm{d}s^2 = -\alpha^2 \chi^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2 + \mathrm{d}\chi^2 +\mathrm{d} y^2 + \mathrm{d}z^2 \text{.} \tag{1}
$$
Hence, the Rindler metric (written in matrix form) is
$$
(g_{\mu\nu}) = \begin{pmatrix} -\alpha^2 \chi^2 &0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} \text{.} \tag{2}
$$
In a homework of my general relativity course I have to proof, that the Rindler metric is invariant under cooridate transformations generated by
$$
\dfrac{\cosh(\alpha\tau)}{\alpha\chi} \partial_\tau - \sinh(\alpha\tau) \partial_\chi \text{.} \tag{3}
$$
I'm struggling a bit with the formulation "generated by". What is meant here?
Maybe it is
$$
x^\mu \to \tilde x^\mu = e^{\theta X} x^\mu \text{,} \tag{4}
$$
where X is the given generator and
$$
(x^\mu)=(\tau,\chi,y,z) \text{.}\tag{5}
$$
But I don't know, what I should do further...
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the Lie derivative of the metric with respect to the given vector field in eq (3). Alternatively and equivalently  look at
$$
g_{\mu\nu}(x+\epsilon\eta) d(x^\mu+\epsilon\eta^\mu) d(x^\nu+\epsilon\eta^\mu)
$$
where $\eta^\mu$ are the components of the  vector field  $\eta^\mu \partial_\mu$ of eq(3) and $\epsilon$ is small.

Comment: Ok thx! I will try it. And then present my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

We start with (definition of $\eta$ see mike stones comment)
$$
x^\mu\to \tilde x^\mu = e^{\epsilon \eta}x^\mu = \left(1+\epsilon \eta + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2) \right) x^\mu \text{.} \tag{6}
$$
Thus it is
$$
(g_{\mu\nu})=\begin{pmatrix} -\alpha^2(\chi^2 -2 \epsilon \chi \sinh(\alpha\tau)) &0 &0 &0\\0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} \text{.}\tag{7}
$$

I still do not know, what the lee
Now we have to transform the differentials
$$
\mathrm{d}\tilde\tau = \mathrm{d}(\tau+\epsilon \dfrac{\cosh(\alpha\tau)}{\alpha \chi}) = (1+\epsilon \dfrac{\sinh(\alpha\tau)}{\chi})\mathrm{d}\tau - \epsilon\dfrac{\cosh(\alpha\tau)}{\alpha \chi^2} \mathrm{d}\chi \tag{8}
$$
$$
\mathrm{d}\tilde\chi =  \mathrm{d}(\chi-\epsilon \sinh(\alpha\tau)) = \mathrm{d}\chi - \epsilon \alpha \cosh(\alpha\tau)\mathrm{d} \tau \tag{9}
$$
$$
\mathrm{d}\tilde y = \mathrm{d}y \tag{10}
$$
$$
\mathrm{d}\tilde z = \mathrm{d}z \tag{11}
$$
This results in
$$
\begin{align}
&g_{\mu\nu}(x+\epsilon \eta) \mathrm{d}(x^\mu + \epsilon \eta^\mu)\mathrm{d}(x^\nu + \epsilon \eta^\nu) \\&= -\alpha^2(\chi^2-2\epsilon\chi\sinh(\alpha\tau))\left[\left(1+\epsilon \dfrac{\sinh(\alpha\tau)}{\chi}\right)\mathrm{d}\tau - \epsilon\dfrac{\cosh(\alpha\tau)}{\alpha \chi^2} \mathrm{d}\chi \right]^2 + [\mathrm{d}\chi - \epsilon \alpha \cosh(\alpha\tau)\mathrm{d} \tau]^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2+ \mathrm{d}z^2 \\
&= -\alpha^2 \chi^2 \left[\left(1+2\epsilon \dfrac{\sinh(\alpha \tau)}{\chi}\right)\mathrm{d}\tau^2 - 2 \epsilon \dfrac{\cosh(\alpha\tau)}{\alpha \chi^2} \mathrm{d}\tau \mathrm{d}\chi \right] + 2 \epsilon \alpha^2 \chi \sinh(\alpha \tau) \mathrm{d}\tau^2 + \mathrm{d}\chi^2 - 2\epsilon \alpha \cosh(\alpha \tau) \mathrm{d}\tau \mathrm{d}\chi + \mathrm{d}y^2+ \mathrm{d}z^2  \\
&=-\alpha^2 \chi^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2 + \mathrm{d}\chi^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2+ \mathrm{d}z^2\text{.}
\end{align}
$$
I still do not know, what a Lie derivative is. I will google it^^ And then if possible add the solution with the lie derivative.
Thanks a lot mike! :)

Comment: If you have a vector field $\xi$, then it generates a flow $\Phi$ (i.e for small $\epsilon$, $\Phi_{\epsilon}:M \to M$ is a diffeomorphism on the manifold... this is pretty much what you're doing by writing $x^{\mu} \to \tilde{x}^{\mu}$). Now, we can consider how the metric tensor field varies along the flow; i.e consider the pullback tensor field $(\Phi_{\epsilon})^*g$, and then take the derivative at $\epsilon = 0$. i.e $\mathcal{L}_{\xi}g := \dfrac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon = 0} (\Phi_{\epsilon})^*g$.

Comment: So, this measures in some sense how much the metric $g$ "varies along the flow generated by the vector field $\xi$". What your calculation showed is that $(\Phi_{\epsilon})^*g = g + o(\epsilon)$, i.e to first order in $\epsilon$ (i.e for "small coordinate transformations") the metric $g$ doesn't change. It is in this sense that the vector field leaves the Rindler metric invariant.

Comment: Thank you very much peek-a-boo :) Maybe i should read chapter about differential geometry in a math book. I'll try to give the solution with the Lie derivative soon :)

Comment: But another question is: Doesn't my calculation show $(\Phi_\epsilon)^*g=g + o(\epsilon^2)$ ? I only throw out $o(\epsilon^2)$ terms.

Comment: Note that $o(\epsilon)$ and $O(\epsilon^2)$, and $o(\epsilon^2)$ all mean different things. Let's define $R(\epsilon) = \Phi^*_{\epsilon}g - g$. We say $R_{\epsilon}$ is $o(\epsilon)$ if $\dfrac{R_{\epsilon}}{\epsilon}\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$. We say $R(\epsilon)$ is $O(\epsilon^2)$ if $\dfrac{R_{\epsilon}}{\epsilon^2}$ is bounded in a punctured neighbourhood of $\epsilon = 0$ (i.e we evaluate at a point $p \in M$ to we get $\epsilon \mapsto R_{\epsilon}(p)/\epsilon^2$, which is a function from $\Bbb{R}-0 \to T_pM$, and we ask that this function is bounded in a neighborhood of $\epsilon= 0$ )

Comment: Finally, there is $o(\epsilon^2)$ which means we want $\frac{R_{\epsilon}}{\epsilon^2} \to 0$. Which is of course a completely different condition. Now, first derivatives are always $o(\epsilon)$ (note that $O(\epsilon^2)$ and $o(\epsilon^2)$ imply $o(\epsilon)$, but not conversely). So, no all your calculation shows is $o(\epsilon)$ (or perhaps $O(\epsilon^2)$ if you had more carefully tracked all the remainders). But anyway the "proper" translation of the phrase "to first order in $\epsilon$" is to say it is $o(\epsilon)$. (by the way, I apologize for $R(\epsilon)$ vs $R_{\epsilon}$)

Comment: Oh ok! I am a bachelor student of physics in Germany. I think we just used the big O notation so far. I thought, $o(\epsilon)$ and $O(\epsilon)$ would be the same! Thank you for clarification!